# Illegalstateexception activity has been destroyed fragmenttransaction.commit()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have seen a few versions of this question before, but the reasons for this exception were different than my own it seems.

What I am trying to do:

### -Main Activity class has a toolbar at the bottom, clicking the buttons will display a series of fragments, one after another.

### - A class EditItemFragmentManager, which is instatiated on a button click, and has methods that display specific fragments based on the toolbar button clicked.

I would like to use this manager class I created because it cleans my code up significantly and will make adding more features later helpful.

Here is my EditItemFragmentManager class, I am  not sure if extending Activity is a good idea or not, I think that it will put my MainActivity on pause

```
public class EditItemFragmentManager extends Activity{
//instance variables

public EditItemFragmentManager(){
// initialization of some variables
}


public void editItem(){
editItemSequence();
}

private void editItemSequence(){
EditNameFragment enf = new EditNameFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(editNameFragment, EDIT_FRAG_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(EDIT_FRAG_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

}
```

So it blows up when commit(); is called, giving me

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

This is how I am trying to get this fragment from my MainActivity,

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditIteFragmetManager manager = new EditIteFragmetManager();
                manager.editItem();
            }
```

I am still learning about the Acvtivity lifecycle in Android. I think my problem is something due to this class extending Activity, which puts my Main on pause, and the FragmentTransaction has nothing to commit to? If so, I need to get the existing instance of my main activity and call it on that? This is where I'm a bit lost, if anyone who understands the lifecycle of Activities/Fragments explain how I could go about implementing this while still having a helper class such as this?

Comment: that is the only erorr?

Comment: yes, according to the stack.

Comment: I do not have an onCreate yet implemented for this class, essentially the constructor handles everything the class needs. If I did implement it, I would just call super and initialize variables as I did in the constructor

Comment: no no no, wrong you need to put all you initialization inside the oncreate, that is where you error come from. put it in there and update me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SupportFragmentManager, then you need to extend from FragmentActivity, and not just Activity. Also make sure that you imported the Fragment from the v4 support library, and not android.app.

Other than that, you seem to be instantiating a subclass of Activity with "new", which is terrible. Create activities only using Intents.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by moving my manager class to become a private inner class of my main, since they are so tightly coupled. No fragment issues now.